# Finding out of a set of 3x1 matrices are linearly independent or dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I know how to determine if any $2 \times 2$ matrix or $3 \times 3$ matrix is linearly dependent/independent; It's easy, as long as the determinant of the matrix $\ne 0 \implies $ **linearly independent**, and if the determinant does $= 0$ then it is **linearly dependent**.. My question is tho;

> How exactly can I determine if a set of $3 \times 1$ matrices are linearly independent /dependent?
>
> $a) \begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1\\5\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-1\\6\\9\end{bmatrix}$
>
> Also,
>
> How can I determine if a single $2 \times 1$ matrix is linearly independent/dependent?
>
> $b) \begin{bmatrix}-6\\2\end{bmatrix}$

Please explain by using the example problems I've given.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the definition of linear (in)dependence?

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/linear-independence/v/linear-algebra-introduction-to-linear-independence

Comment: Notice that a set of two vector is linearly independent iff neither vector is a multiple of the other, and a set consisting of one vector is linearly independent iff the vector is nonzero.  (Also, your statement about the determinants of matrices only applies if you're showing the columns or rows of the matrix are linearly independent -- not the matrix itself.)

Comment: so when you say they aren;'t multiples of each other... you mean that as long as the corresponding row entries are not multiple of each other for each row right? or that every single corresponding row entry is not a multiple? can u give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition:** A set of vectors $\{\mathbf u_1, \dots, \mathbf u_k\}\subset \Bbb R^n$ is linearly independent if $$a_1\mathbf u_1 + \cdots + a_k\mathbf u_k = \mathbf 0 \implies a_1 = \cdots = a_k=0$$

So let's check if $\{(-6,2)\}$ is a linearly independent set.  For we write down $\mathbf 0$ as a linear combination of the set:  $$(0,0) = a(-6,2)$$  Are there *any* solutions to this other than $a=0$?  Well this equation is equivalent to the system of equations $\begin{cases} 0=-6a \\ 0 = 2a\end{cases}$.  Hopefully you can see very quickly that the only solution to either equation (and thus both) is $a=0$.  Thus $$(0,0) = a(-6,2) \implies a=0$$ and therefore $\{(-6,2)\}$ is a linearly independent set.

---

Now while **you** test the slightly harder one in part $(a)$ using the usual approach, I'm going to use the wedge product to determine whether the set is linearly independent or not.

$$(-2e_1-e_2+5e_3) \wedge (-e_1+6e_2+9e_3) = -13e_1\wedge e_2 -13e_1\wedge e_3 -39e_2\wedge e_3$$

Therefore the set is $\dots$

Comment: Could i also put the matrix in RREF form to see that $x_1, x_2 , x_3 = 0$?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}-2&-1&0\\-1&6&0\\5&9&0\end{bmatrix}$ ~ $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: It's interesting that you thought of that.  Yes, you can.  You don't even have to add the last column of zeros.  You construct a matrix with your vectors as rows or columns (it doesn't matter which) and row reduce.  If you end up with the same number of pivots as the number of vectors in your set, then they are linearly independent.  If not, then they are linearly dependent.  **However**, I do suggest that you work with the actual definition that I give in my answer so that you can understand what exactly it means.  Then you can use your matrix approach as a way to check yourself.